# Doctrine query select where date at time zone

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a postgres table of events where the event time is stored in a date time with time zone field with UTC as the time zone. The actual time zone is stored in a separate field.

i.e.

id, event_time, time_zone

1, 2013-10-15 10:32:21-05, 'America/Chicago'

2, 2013-10-15 9:32:21-05, 'America/New York'
etc.

I want to use the symfony2/doctrine2 query builder to select events that fall within a certain date range expressed in local time. For example, I might want to select all events between 4pm-5pm local time on 10/15/2013.

In postgres I can achieve this by using the "AT TIME ZONE" function. Is there anything similar available for doctrine's query builder (besides native sql of course).

i.e. "SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_time AT TIME ZONE(time_zone) BETWEEN a AND b"

Comment: I'm not sure if it currently exists but if it doesn't you may be able to create it yourself as noted in http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/basic-mapping.html#custom-mapping-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create a user defined function: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

```
<?php

namespace MyOrganization\Bundle\MyBundle\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;

/**
 * AtTimeZoneFunction ::= "AT_TIME_ZONE" "(" ArithmeticPrimary "," ArithmeticPrimary ")"
 */
class AtTimeZone extends FunctionNode {

  // (1)
  public $dateExpression = null;
  public $timezoneExpression = null;

  public function parse(Parser $parser) {
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER); // (2)
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS); // (3)
    $this->dateExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary(); // (4)
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA); // (5)
    $this->timezoneExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary(); // (6)
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS); // (3)
  }

  public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker) {
    return $this->dateExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ' AT TIME ZONE ( '
      . $this->timezoneExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) .
    ')'; // (7)
  }

}
```